# Android Google Assistant open my app with just app name

Tags: android, android-deep-link, google-assistant, app-actions

I saw Google Assistant codelabs and implemented open app via Google Assistant. I am using `actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE` intent, it is not working what i expected. For example, It works when i say "Hey google open myAppName app/application/work/run". But i wanted it opens my app when i say "Hey google appName". Could anyone help me to resolve it? Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
     <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://app.page.link/open{?featureName}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="feature"
            urlParameter="featureName" />
    </fulfillment>
    <parameter name="feature">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeaturesSetId"/>
    </parameter>
   </action>

<entity-set entitySetId="FeaturesSetId">
    <entity name="App" identifier="app"/>
    <entity name="Application" identifier="application"/>
    <entity name="Work" identifier="work"/>
    <entity name="Run" identifier="run"/>
</entity-set>
</actions>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/action-schema

Comment: I tried saying "open myAppName" or just "myAppName" on Android 12 on my device and it work on every app.

Answer (score 0):

App Actions BIIs don't recognize requests that are outside of its predefined language patterns.  You can see from the [open app feature documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature#example-queries) that it recognizes patterns such as:

- Open Youtube history.
- Open ExampleApp ExampleFeature.
- Show me ExampleFeature on ExampleApp.

So, what you're trying to do is likely unsupported by open app feature.

If you want to use language patterns that are not supported by a BII, then you will need to look into using a [custom intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/custom-intents).