# is it possible to use actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE with dynamic value

Tags: google-assistant, app-actions

I have an application that loads a dynamic list of buttons and want to allow a user to click a button by its name using google assistant.
It is possible using actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE or I must use custom intent for that ?

Comment: just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67606642/702267 so I assume this is not possible ?